# chrome-aws-lambda rendered image is different than chrome

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium, echarts

### Environment

- `chrome-aws-lambda` Version: 2.0.1
- `puppeteer` / `puppeteer-core` Version:  2.0.0
- OS: Amazon Linux 2
- Node.js Version: 10.x
- Lambda / GCF Runtime: nodejs10.x

### Expected Behavior

[image: expected]

Text lines are not overlapped. (This image is rendered from my PC which is running debian linux)

### Current Behavior

[image: chrome-aws-lambda-image]

Text lines are overlapped when running on aws lambda.

### Possible Solution

N/A

### Steps to Reproduce

Render text element on canvas with multiple lines separated by the new line character. For example: '7.1%\nFLR{sub|95}'

**Note**: These graphics are rendered from [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#title) charting library.

Comment: Have you tried using "--font-render-hinting" flag with chromium?

Comment: Thanks @MarterJay I tried it. but didn't show any difference.